# How to make a single row from the model appear twice in the view?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developping an application that has a QTableView to display values coming from a QAbstractTableModel. Everything is now working well, but I would like to go further and provide to the user the ability to display several times the same row into the view.

My idea for achieving this was to use a Proxy model, so I subclassed QAbstractProxyModel to do this. Unfortunately this won't do the job: there is no way I could find to properly implement mapFromSource, since two or more rows from the view could correspond to the same row into the model, and mapFromSource only returns a single QModelIndex.

As far as possible, I'd like to keep my model as it is, since it is a very convenient way to handle the kind of data I store.

Is there a way to do this using proxy models anyway? Or am I just thinking the wrong way and I need another concept?

Comment: Well, I guess you have good reasons to display the rows more than once. Then the logic of `mapFromSource` is all up to you I think, you arbitrary decide to return one of the `QModelIndex` that matches the *sourceIndex*. They will all depend on your *sourceIndex* anyway and all get updated right ? In my opinion they are basically the same data so it does not matter which one you return.

Comment: I just tried this option and it works. I can't fully understand why but it seems to... Thank you!